# How does the Grub menu actually Works?

Tags: grub-legacy

After installing Ubuntu alongside Windows (Dual - boot) , I found that , no matter which partition I set as  active (bootable) ,  Grub Menu automatically comes & I can boot to any O/s.

I marked  C, D & E drives bootable one by one and it works to be fine  in every case , while earlier in case of Windows(only Windows installed) , I got a  "No os found" or "Boot Mgr is missing"  , error message , on  doing similar stuff.

How Grub is independent of  , whether a partition is set active or not ?

Comment: I am not asking for help , just curious about how it is working , even though if I making my E drive ,( which just contain my multimedia stuff)  ACTIVE.

Comment: The partition which is marked as active , is the one which is called during start-up & I am not saying it is an Ubuntu problem.

Comment: Yes , I said I can boot to any o/s , i.e both Ubuntu & Windows . I am  just asking how it (Grub)  loads during start-up , though the active partition , doesn't contain any files regarding that.

Comment: Active in Windows is boot flag in Ubuntu. And grub does not use boot flag. Windows boot loaders & syslinux use boot flag to find additional boot code in the partition boot sector. Old but still how BIOS works. http://www.multibooters.com/guides/visual-guide-to-the-boot-sequence.html But if new UEFI, the boot flag (with gparted) is used to assign a very long GUID which UEFI then knows as the FAT32 partition with more boot files. Other tools use different methods to assign GUID.

Comment: Thanks @oldfred do you mind if I use your comment in my answer?

Comment: @ Oldfred , Thanks  for the explanation

Comment: Yes , it is  solved ,  but still there is a confusing , that MBR exist in a System Reserved Partition of 100 Mb iin Windows 7 , which must be marked active for booting Windows , then how Grub is managing to boot both Ubuntu & Windows depending upon my choice.

Comment: Grub2's os-prober also does not use boot flag to find Windows bootable partition with BIOS. It searches for bootmgr & /Boot/BCD to find which partition has Windows boot files. For UEFI it searches the /EFI/Microsoft folder for Windows bootmgfw.efi bootable file.

Comment: Thanks , it cleared all of  my doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Windows and Ubuntu use different bootloaders

Ubuntu uses grub. Windows uses BCD.

Part of grub resides in the Master Boot Record (MBR) or in the EFI System Partition (ESP) depending on whether your computer boots in legacy BIOS or UEFI mode.

The MBR lives in the first few bytes of the physical drive, not to be confused with a partition like what Windows calls C "Drive".

In computers with UEFI the Windows does not assign a "drive" letter to the ESP by default.

From [@oldfred](https://askubuntu.com/users/126395/oldfred)'s comment:

`Active` in Windows is `boot-flag` in Ubuntu. **Grub does not use the `boot-flag`**. Windows' bootloaders and Linux'es syslinux use `boot-flag` to find additional boot code in the partition boot sector. This is still how the legacy BIOS works.

See [A visual guide to the boot sequence](http://www.multibooters.com/guides/visual-guide-to-the-boot-sequence.html) for more details.

The new computers with UEFI and GUID partition table (GPT) based systems, the `boot-flag` is used to assign a very long GUID to the ESP. The UEFI then knows  the FAT32 partition assigned to be the ESP, where parts of bootloaders and other boot files are stored.

See [Managing EFI bootloaders](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) for more details.

That's why you can boot Ubuntu using grub even when you set D: as bootable in Windows.

Comment: Actually,  in Windows you can assign a drive letter to the ESP partition using *diskpart*. It's just that by default Windows makes it inaccessible for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This explains [how grub boots multiple drives and partitions](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/DOS_002fWindows.html#DOS_002fWindows):

### 5.3.4 DOS/Windows

GRUB cannot boot DOS or Windows directly, so you must chain-load them (see [Chain-loading](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Chain_002dloading.html#Chain_002dloading)). However, their boot loaders have some critical deficiencies, so it may not work to just chain-load them. To overcome the problems, GRUB provides you with two helper functions.

If you have installed DOS (or Windows) on a non-first hard disk, you have to use the disk swapping technique, because that OS cannot boot from any disks but the first one. The workaround used in GRUB is the command drivemap (see [drivemap](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/drivemap.html#drivemap)), like this:

```
drivemap -s (hd0) (hd1)
```

This performs a virtual swap between your first and second hard drive.

Caution: This is effective only if DOS (or Windows) uses BIOS to access the swapped disks. If that OS uses a special driver for the disks, this probably won’t work.

Another problem arises if you installed more than one set of DOS/Windows onto one disk, because they could be confused if there are more than one primary partitions for DOS/Windows. Certainly you should avoid doing this, but there is a solution if you do want to do so. Use the partition hiding/unhiding technique.

If GRUB hides a DOS (or Windows) partition (see [parttool](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/parttool.html#parttool)), DOS (or Windows) will ignore the partition. If GRUB unhides a DOS (or Windows) partition, DOS (or Windows) will detect the partition. Thus, if you have installed DOS (or Windows) on the first and the second partition of the first hard disk, and you want to boot the copy on the first partition, do the following:

```
parttool (hd0,1) hidden-
parttool (hd0,2) hidden+
set root=(hd0,1)
chainloader +1
parttool ${root} boot+
boot
```

### Notes from `parttool`:

> #### ‘boot’ (boolean)
>
> - When enabled, this makes the selected partition be the active (bootable) partition on its disk, clearing the active flag on all
>   other partitions. This command is limited to primary partitions.
>
> #### ‘type’ (value)
>
> - Change the type of an existing partition. The value must be a number in the range 0-0xFF (prefix with ‘0x’ to enter it in
>   hexadecimal).
>
> #### ‘hidden’ (boolean)
>
> - When enabled, this hides the selected partition by setting the hidden bit in its partition type code; when disabled, unhides the
>   selected partition by clearing this bit. This is useful only when
>   booting DOS or Windows and multiple primary FAT partitions exist in
>   one disk. See also DOS/Windows.